# 画像から特定の色を抽出したい

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

[image: 判定前の画像]
[image: 判定後の画像]
お世話になります。画像から赤、緑の色を抽出して色の点群を矩形で囲みたいのですが、HSVのどのパターンを試してもうまくいきません。今は青はうまくいっていますが一部ずれていたり、関係のないところにもかかっています。プログラムのような色の探し方が悪いのか、別な範囲を変えたらいいのかよくわからないでいます。どなたか解決法を教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
col_img=cv2.imread("/home/pi/seisaku/2.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)   
col_img=cv2.resize(col_img,None,fx=3,fy=3)
img=cv2.cvtColor(col_img,cv2.cv.CV_BGR2HSV)

h=copy.copy(img[:,:,0])
s=copy.copy(img[:,:,1])
v=copy.copy(img[:,:,2])

Blue=np.zeros(col_img.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
Red=np.zeros(col_img.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
Green=np.zeros(col_img.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
Blue[((h > 200) | (h < 260)) & (s > 100)]=255
Red[((h < 30) | (h > 280)) & (s > 128)]=255
Green[((h > 80) | (h < 230)) & (s > 170)]=255

for col in [Red,Blue,Green]:
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(col, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    retval, bw = cv2.threshold(gray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imwrite("bw.jpg",bw)

    contours,_= cv2.findContours(bw, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    ##各輪郭に対する処理
    for i in range(0, len(contours)):

        # 輪郭の領域を計算
        area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])

        # 外接矩形
        if( len(contours[i]) > 0 )&(100<area<400):
            rect = contours[i]
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(rect)
            if abs(w-h)<5:
                cv2.rectangle(col_img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255,0 ,0), 2)
            #print(int(x+w/2),int(y+h/2))

            cv2.imwrite("aux.jpg",col_img)
            #cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Blue[((h > 200) | (h < 260)) & (s > 100)]=255
> Red[((h < 30) | (h > 280)) & (s > 128)]=255
> Green[((h > 80) | (h < 230)) & (s > 170)]=255
> ```

色相(`h`)を角度[0,360)で判定したいという意図でしょうか？OpenCVによるHSV変換後の値域は0〜179となるため、この判定式はあなたの想定通りに機能しません。

---

質問ソースコードをベースに、マーカー判定基準を改良してみました。Python 3＋OpenCV 3前提としています。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

col_img = cv2.imread("q37984.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
col_img = cv2.resize(col_img, None, fx=3, fy=3)

# HSVチャネル別に分解
img = cv2.cvtColor(col_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h = img[:, :, 0]
s = img[:, :, 1]
v = img[:, :, 2]

shape = (img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1)
Red = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.uint8)
Green = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.uint8)
Blue = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.uint8)
# 色相(Hue)による色成分検出; +彩度(S)と明度(V)の閾値判定
HF = 0.5
Red[((h < 0*HF) | (h > 300*HF)) & (s > 16) & (v > 128)] = 255     # 330±30°
Green[((h > 30*HF) & (h < 90*HF)) & (s > 16) & (v > 128)] = 255   # 60±30°
Blue[((h > 180*HF) & (h < 240*HF)) & (s > 16) & (v > 128)] = 255  # 210±30°

# 縮小処理によるノイズ除去(5x5円形カーネル)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
Red = cv2.morphologyEx(Red, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
Green = cv2.morphologyEx(Green, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
Blue = cv2.morphologyEx(Blue, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

ROUND_TH = 0.4  # 円判定閾値

for target in [Red,Green,Blue]:
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(target, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours:
        # 検出輪郭の外接円面積area1を計算
        (cx, cy), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
        area1 = (radius * radius) * math.pi
        # 検出輪郭の実面積area0を計算
        area0 = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        # 面積比率から輪郭の"円形度"を推定
        if (1 - ROUND_TH) < area1 / area0 < (1 + ROUND_TH):
            cv2.circle(col_img, (int(cx), int(cy)), int(radius), (0,0,0), 2)

cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", col_img)
```

結果：
[image: 検出結果]